# FALSE returned when 1 == 1 in R

Tags: r

I am testing the equivalence of two numeric classes, however when the values being compared are a value of 1 or less R returns False, see [console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLnmX.png)

As long as the comparison between the value in loadograph and the value in pulse_endTime are greater than 1, things work, however less than one FALSE is returned. Could it be the way the round function was used here?

loadograph$Time<-round(loadograph$Time, 2);
pulse_endTime<-round(pulse_endTime, 2)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please refer to stackoverflow.com/conduct Don't post your code as Photo, write it. Also, Try using `=` instead of `==`

Comment: The `==` sing is a logical comparator. When you call x==y, it returns true if x is equal to y, or false if not

Comment: You cannot compare floating point (decimal numbers) for exact equality. See  [R FAQ 7.31: Why doesn’t R think these numbers are equal?](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f). See also `?all.equal`.

Comment: Other good links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken. This is not unique to R, it is a fundamental limitation when using constrained bytes to store floating-point numbers, typically implemented using [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).

Comment: Your best option is to see if the absolute-difference is smaller than a threshold. For instance, `abs(loadograph$Time - pulse_endTime[2] - 0.92) < 1e-8`. (The use of `1e-8` is contextual, you may only need `1e-5` or perhaps need even smaller, but don't get too close to `.Machine$neg.eps`.)